# How does RoR cache work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How does Ruby on Rails cache work?

Comment: Which cache? There's the class cache, view cache, query cache, fragment cache, page cache, etc etc. What do you want to know about their internals?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @Zabba and @Chris Heald, expand your comments into answers, nudge, nudge.

Answer (score 3):

There are three types of caching that Ruby on Rails can provide (although it can and does provide more!) that you are probably interested in:

- Page caching
- Action caching
- Fragment caching

There is [an excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) that covers them all.